# Get data from another column where first column id is equals other and other column equals X

Tags: sql, zend-framework

My problem is:
I would like to get all advertistments where id of `Description` column is equals with `Advertistment's` column.

Let's say that `Advertistment` column is connected with `Description` column.
I would like to gain all description's id where one of its column called `type_of_house` is equals `m`.
Then show all advertistment where advertistment's id is equals with description's id.

In short way: advertistment shows info about houses, descriptions store houses type D and M and I want show all advertistments with houses type of M.

This is correct sql:

```
SELECT * FROM advertistment, description WHERE advertistment.id_advertistment = description.id_description AND description.type_of_house = "m"
```

I have no idea how write it into zend. I tried something like that. This function I wrote in model folder.

```
public function takeAll() {
    $select = $this->_db->select();
    $select->from(array('a' => 'advertistment', 'd' => 'description'));
    $select->where('a.id_advertistment = d.id_description AND d.type_of_house = m');
    return $select->query()->fetchAll();
}
```

Comment: sql query works, I don't know how write this sql to zend db command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're actually quite close. This should work:

```
public function takeAll() {
    $select = $this->_db->select();
    $select->from(array('a' => 'advertistment'));
    $select->join(array('d' => 'description'), 'a.id_advertistment = d.id_description');
    $select->where('d.type_of_house = ?', 'm');

    return $this->_db->fetchAll($select);
}
```